# Java Concurrency - Better Design approach to manage thread life cycle (start/stop)

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm designing a concurrent Java application that reads data from various medical devices available on the hospital Intranet.

I've read "Java concurrency in practice - Brian Goetz..." to understand how to do stuff, but I think I'm still missing something.

Here's a [quick simple diagram](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1C54rfxRL0MXykobGF39w-cSSJhxcbszNO8leMnEf4uM/edit?hl=en_US) of what I'm trying to do and there's some code snippet below..

Worker threads (MedicalDeviceData instances) continuously read data from medical devices and make it available for the MedicalDeviceWorkManager, who in turn supplies it to the end user.
The worker threads keep reading data infinitely (ideally) and there's no "work completed" situation in my scenario.
Moreover, user can choose to Start All devices or start a specific device or stop a device as and when he wishes.

Below is code snippet (compiles but not tested) of how I would implement it.

MedicalDeviceWorkManager - Spawns the worker threads and manages them.

MedicalDeviceData - Worker thread gets data from medical devices infinitely and updates this instance of this class.

Mainly look at startDevice, stopDevice and run methods.

You'll obviously notice that I'm not using ThreadPoolExecutor and Future and that I just rolled my own implementation here.

As future.get blocks till a work is completed, it doesnt make sense for my case, because my worker thread never "completes" the task...its just an infinitely ongoing task...

QUESTION:How do I change the implementation shown below to a more standardized one so that I could make better use of java.util.concurrent package (ThreadPoolExecutor/Future).

Any other better design pattern I should look at?

```
public class MedicalDeviceWorkManager {

  private ThreadGroup rootThreadGroup = null;
  Hashtable<String, MedicalDeviceData> deviceObjs = new Hashtable<String, MedicalDeviceData>();

  public void manageMedicalDevices() throws InterruptedException  {

    String[] allDevices={"Device1","Device2","Device3","Device4"};

    //-- Start all threads to collect data
    for(String deviceToStart:allDevices){
      this.startDevice(deviceToStart);
    }

    //-- Stop all threads 
    for(String deviceToStop:allDevices){
      this.stopDevice(deviceToStop);
    }

    //-- Start on request from user
    String deviceToStart="Device1";
    this.startDevice(deviceToStart);

    //-- Stop on request from user.
    String deviceToStop="Device1";
    this.stopDevice(deviceToStop);

    /* 
     * Get Data and give it to client 
     * This is happening via a separate TCP port
     * */
    while(true){
      for(String deviceName:allDevices){
        if(deviceObjs.get(deviceName)!=null){

          ConcurrentHashMap<String,BigDecimal> devData=deviceObjs.get(deviceName).getCollectedData();

          //--Loop and send data to client on TCP stream
          ;
        }
      }//-- loop the devices
    }//-- infinite
  }

  //-- Start the device to start acquiring data using a worker thread
  private void startDevice(String deviceName){
    //-- Get Device instance
    MedicalDeviceData thisDevice=deviceObjs.get(deviceName);
    if(thisDevice==null){
      thisDevice=new MedicalDeviceData(deviceName);
      deviceObjs.put(deviceName, thisDevice);
    }

    //-- Create thread to start data acquisition 
    //-- Start if not being processed already (Handle what if thread hung scenario later)
    if(this.getThread(deviceName)==null){
      Thread t=new Thread(thisDevice);
      t.setName(deviceName);
      t.start();          
    }
  }


  //-- Stop the worker thread thats collecting the data.
  private void stopDevice(String deviceName) throws InterruptedException {
    deviceObjs.get(deviceName).setShutdownRequested(true);
    Thread t=this.getThread(deviceName);
    t.interrupt();
    t.join(1000);
  }

  private Thread getThread( final String name ) {
    if ( name == null )
        throw new NullPointerException( "Null name" );
    final Thread[] threads = getAllThreads( );
    for ( Thread thread : threads )
        if ( thread.getName( ).equals( name ) )
            return thread;
    return null;
  }

  private ThreadGroup getRootThreadGroup( ) {
      if ( rootThreadGroup != null )
          return rootThreadGroup;
      ThreadGroup tg = Thread.currentThread( ).getThreadGroup( );
      ThreadGroup ptg;
      while ( (ptg = tg.getParent( )) != null )
          tg = ptg;
      return tg;
  } 

  private Thread[] getAllThreads( ) {
    final ThreadGroup root = getRootThreadGroup( );
    final ThreadMXBean thbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
    int nAlloc = thbean.getThreadCount( );
    int n = 0;
    Thread[] threads;
    do {
        nAlloc *= 2;
        threads = new Thread[ nAlloc ];
        n = root.enumerate( threads, true );
    } while ( n == nAlloc );
    return java.util.Arrays.copyOf( threads, n );
  }

}//-- MedicalDeviceWorkManager




public class MedicalDeviceData implements Runnable{

  //-- Data Collected from medical device
  private final ConcurrentHashMap<String,BigDecimal> collectedData=new ConcurrentHashMap<String,BigDecimal>();

  //-- Set by Thread Manager to request a shutdown..after which it should interrupt the thread
  private AtomicBoolean shutdownRequested;

  //-- Simple data Counter
  private AtomicInteger dataCounter=new AtomicInteger(0);

  //-- Device Name
  private String thisDeviceName;

  public void run() {

    //-- Initialize I/O for the device
    ;

    while(!this.getShutdownRequested()){
      try{
        //-- just to compile the code
        Thread.sleep(0);

        //-- perform I/O operation to get data from medical device
        ;

        //-- Add data into the ConcurrentHashMap...Both key and value are immutable.
        collectedData.put("DataKey", new BigDecimal("9999"));

        //-- data counter
        dataCounter.getAndIncrement();

      }
      catch(InterruptedException ie){
        if(this.getShutdownRequested()){
          return;
        }
        //throw new InterruptedException();
      }
    }

  }//-- run

  public MedicalDeviceData(String thisDeviceName){
    this.thisDeviceName=thisDeviceName;
  }

  /**
   * @return the shutdownRequested
   */
  public boolean getShutdownRequested() {
    return this.shutdownRequested.get();
  }


  /**
   * @param shutdownRequested the shutdownRequested to set
   */
  public void setShutdownRequested(boolean shutdownRequested) {
    this.shutdownRequested.set(shutdownRequested);
  }


  /**
   * Both key and value are immutable, so ok to publish reference.
   * 
   * @return the collectedData
   */
  public ConcurrentHashMap<String, BigDecimal> getCollectedData() {
    return collectedData;
  }


  /**
   * @return the dataCounter
   */
  public AtomicInteger getDataCounter() {
    return dataCounter;
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe the worker threads should send their data through the (synchronized) socket themselves.  I don't like your main while loop that sends the TCP with a for loop over the devices.  Actually, do you really send new information continuously? or do you check if a value was updated before sending it?

Comment: Instead of ThreadGroup, a HashMap<String, Thread> might give you cleaner code.

Comment: You can easily use a ThreadPoolExecutor (without Future).  It does execute normal Runnable (even if non-terminating).  But you would still need to communicate with the threads with some synchronized data structure to indicate termination (maybe a Hashtable<String,AtomicBoolean>), like you did with shutdownRequested.

Comment: are all the methods that get or put to deviceObjs GUARANTEED to be from a single thread? As an aside, that's not threadsafe otherwise.

Comment: @toto:I send all new data, not just changed stuff. Thanks for your suggestions. @MJB:I need to make it thread-safe. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob's comment got me thinking about a possible alternative solution.  You can utilize an ExecutorService in which a start would submit to said service.  When the runnable completes and pause or stop were not selected then the callable will re submit itself to the service.  So you will now effectively have only a pre determined number of threads running with sequential consistency amongst work execution.

A lot of the code is still the same just underlying execution would differ.

```
public class MedicalDeviceWorkManager {

   private ConcurrentHashMap<String, DelegatedWorker > devices = new ConcurrentHashMap<...>();

   private final ExecutorService worker = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

   public void registerDevice(String device, Runnable singleUnitOfWork){
         devices.put(device,new DelegatedWorker (singleUnitOfWork));
   } 

   public void startDevice(String device){
        devices.get(device).startDevice();
   }    
   public void stopDevice(String device){
        devices.remove(device).stopDevice();
   }    
   public void pauseDevice(String device){
        devices.get(device).pauseDevice();
   }    
   private class DelegatedWorker { 
      private final Runnable r;
      private volatile Future<?> running;
      DelegatedWorker (Runnable r) {this.r =r ;}

       public void startDevice(){
            if(running != null){
               running = worker.submit(new Callable<Object>(){

                public Object call(){
                     if(Thread.interrupted())return null;
                        r.run();
                     if(Thread.interrupted())return null;

                     return worker.submit(this);
                   }
              });
             }           
       }    
       public void stopDevice(){
            pauseDevice();
       }    
       public void pauseDevice(){
          if(running!=null){ 
              running.cancel(true);
              running = null;
           }
       }    
     }
   }
```

Keep in mind here, instead of a volatile Future, you may want one which you lock around because of the compound function included in `pauseDevice()`

Comment: I like this solution approach....it utilizes the j.u.c package better , uses limited threads.  Thanks John, Rob and others.

Answer (score 2):

So a thread pool may or may not be the best usage here because there is no real abstraction of work.  However this may an interesting use case for extending Thread.  I would handle the communication with simple j.u.c.Lock and j.u.c.Condition.  Finally, I would delegate stopping and starting to specific delegation classes that accept a Runnable type as individual constant units of work.

The only difference I would is to use stop to shutdown and pause to suspend which the start will just continue the work.  For example it could look something like this.

```
public class MedicalDeviceWorkManager {

   private ConcurrentHashMap<String, DelegatingThread> devices = new ConcurrentHashMap<...>();

   public synchronized void registerDevice(String device, Runnable singleUnitOfWork){
         DelegatingThread worker = new DelegatingThread(singleUnitOfWork);
         devices.put(device,worker);

         worker.start();

   } 
   public void startDevice(String device){
        devices.get(device).startDevice();
   }    
   public void stopDevice(String device){
        devices.get(device).stopDevice();
   }    
   public void pauseDevice(String device){
        devices.get(device).pauseDevice();
   }    

   private static class DelegatingThread extends Thread{
      final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
      final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
      final Runnable r;
      boolean paused = true;
      boolean stopped =false;
      private DelegatingThread (Runnable r){ this.r = r; }
      @Override
      public void run(){
          while(true){

             lock.lock(); 
             while(paused)
              condition.await(); 

             if(stopped) return;

             lock.unlock();

             r.run();
          }
      }
      private void startDevice(){
            lock.lock(); 
            paused = false;
            condition.signal(); 
            lock.unlock();
      }
      private void pauseDevice(){
            lock.lock(); 
            if(!stopped)
               paused = true;
            lock.unlock();
      }
      private void stopDevice(){
            lock.lock(); 
            stopped= true;
            paused=false;
            condition.signal();
            lock.unlock();
      }
   } 
}
```

I understand this is a lot of code to demonstrate but the same principles behind a thread pool holds here.  You will always create one thread per device and you reuse when necessary.  The runnable would be the single function you run in between the while loop.

Also, I didn't include the try/finally semantics for brevity.

Comment: @Jon V, @Enno Shioji:Thanks for the elegant solutions laid out. I'll look into them.

Comment: How many devices might there be? The whole reason for a thread pool is that device-per-client does not scale well past a small number of threads.

Comment: @Rob thats a good point to consider.  However, creating 100-200 threads isn't necessarily terrible.  Its running them all at the same time that would be devastating.  If more then the small number of threads you were eluding to would be running all at the same time, this design may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would question your conclusion that the concurrency package is not designed for your needs. My experience is that what is there (thanks to Doug Lea et al) is absurdly complete.

The whole idea of the thread pool and Future interface is to have the threads do tasks that are potentially only *a small part of a larger whole*. This is the idea behind NIO and now continuations in Servlet 3.0. Consider downloading a file. With a servlet 2.x approach, the thread is locked into stewarding each byte and cannot do anything in between packets. With continuations, each packet is a piece of work and the threads are free to do other things between them.

I had occasion to use the project JSpider a few years ago. It was written with old code, pre JDK 5. I wrestled with it then threw it out and did a new one using 5 and threadpools and Future. It's a tiny amount of code and works beautifully.

To me the obvious adaptation here is that you should read chunks of data. Make the size of the chunks configurable. You may think that sounds less efficient. Guarantee you it will not be. Even the lowly UART controller on modems had a buffer. Fill it, then move the contents, then fill it again.

Comment: I havent given up on the concurrency package..I'm not sure how to best use it in my scenario :)
If I understand right,your suggestion is to treat acquisition of a certain (configurable) chunk of data as "unit of work". And with that said,
I could then make use of Future/FutureTask, ThreadPoolExecutor etc...
So everytime I submit a task to do the "unit of work", I'll have to initialize MedicalDeviceData (init I/O and other things needed).  
Is this the approach you are suggesting?  I just want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: You don't have to keep reinitializing anything. Future takes a Callable. Just make that do what you need it to do, the collaborators will be there each time it's invoked.

Comment: The confusing thing about Future is that it's basically saying 'hey, I will go do this work and call you when it's done.' In that way, it's like a completion port (in NT). If all you are doing is relaying data as you say (and show in your diagram), that's a perfect fit. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of code so I have to confess I didn't read it through, but from what I have skimmed, I think you could take this approach.

a) Treat each devices as "actors" i.e. have a single thread which interacts with the actual devices. This thread will read from the devices, and whenever there is an update, submit it to the "manager-service". You may find [AbstractService](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r45/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractService.html) and [ExecutorService.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) useful for this. (`AbstractService` gives you a neat interface on start/stopping device. It'll be excellent for your requirements). Let's call these "device-service".

b) Have a "manager-service", which keeps a set of "device-service"s in a collection. "manager-service" should be again an actor, having its own threads (one thread sounds fine from what I read). The executor service in the manager-service will take from its queue the updates from device-services and does whatever necessary (send it, etc.). This queue is populated by the device-services and polled by the manager-service (classic producer/consumer pattern).

So, like this:

```
class Manager extends AbstractService {
    final ConcurrentMap<Device, DeviceService> deviceServices = // blah
    final ExecutorService exec = // single thread exec

    //called by API user
    newDevice(Device device){
        DeviceService service = new DeviceService(this,device);
        deviceServices.put(device,service);
        service.start();
    }

    //called only by device-services
    void notifyUpdate(final Device device, final Data data){
        Runnable whatever = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                sendStuff.(device.name(), data);
            }
        }
        exec.execute(whatever);
    }

    // blah blah blah blah....

    // called by API user
    public void stop(Device device){
        deviceServices.get(device).stop();
    }
```

and

```
class DeviceService extends AbstractService {
    final Manager mng;
    final Device device;
    final ScheduledExecutorService poller = // single thread
    DeviceService(Manager mng, Device device){
        //blah
    }

    // schedule a task that polls device and calls "notifyUpdate" of mng
    // Whenever there is an update.
    void start(){
        poller.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
           // poll device, and then call mng.notifyUpdate(device, data)

    // blah blah blah blah....
```

Comment: @Jon V, @Enno Shioji:Thanks for the elegant solutions laid out. I'll look into them.